# Write mathjax and text in the same line

Tags: support, mathjax

This is not duplicated.

I know how to use the $ sign, but I want to write **long** equations and words after **in the same line** and I don't know how.

For example if I write:

$2=1+1=2(0.5+0.5)=\sum_{n=1}^40.5=\sum_{n=1}^21$this is happening

I can't use the $$ because this will split the output to two different lines.

How can I do that?

Comment: By the way I'm using my smartphone so maybe you can't see the bug...

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 2):

Use single dollars and \displaystyle and be sure to place spaces *outside* the dollars:

Text before

If I want to write $\displaystyle 2=1+1=2(0.5+0.5)=\sum_{n=1}^40.5=\sum_{n=1}^21$, this is happening but now it looks fine, at least to me, and the paragraph continues neatly.

Text after

Answer (score 1):

That's a feature.  The two dollar-sign method is supposed to break the stuff between it onto its own line.

Is this what you're trying to do?

$$2=1+1=2(0.5+0.5)=\sum_{n=1}^40.5=\sum_{n=1}^21\text{this is happening}$$

Comment: I want the text to look like regular text, but basically yes